# Add delimiters between columns and remove log file time on left

Tags: powershell

I have a question regarding PowerShell and parsing/formatting data.

I currently have data that looks like this:

```
10:23:46   Starting execution of script
10:23:46   Default user will be svc_consumption
10:23:46   Checking Data Domain Available Space
10:23:48    Model number: DD890 - 07/15/2016 10:23:46 - 139.18.40.21 -
10:23:50    Model number: DD890 - 07/15/2016 10:23:46 - 103.153.18.28 -
10:23:52    Model number: DD890 - 07/15/2016 10:23:46 - 12.19.41.75 -

10:24:02    Model number: DD880 - 07/15/2016 10:23:46 - 103.6.28.71 -
10:24:04    Model number: DD890 - 07/15/2016 10:23:46 - 10.116.83.12 -
10:24:05    Model number: DD4500 - 07/15/2016 10:23:46 - 10.18.31.86 -
10:24:06    Model number: DD4500 - 07/15/2016 10:23:46 - 10.18.23.10 -
```

I was wondering what everyone's thoughts were how to parse this data by removing the log times and putting in a semi-colon as a delimiter.
I've tried a few but all my attempts are too complicated.
Any ideas?

**Thanks to anyone who helped!**

Edit: was hoping to get something like "DD890;07/15/2016:10:23:46;139.18.40.21"

Comment: "putting in a semi-colon as a delimiter" - where? What would you like to delimit? :-)

Comment: Please submit a sample line of how you would like it delimited.

Comment: It's probably just overkill. More work than the benefit. If you need to export it that way it would be a different story.

Comment: Based on your edit, for what you're looking for, do you *always* expect `DD` to be present after `Model number:` or can it be something else?  Like `CC`, for example (hint, hint)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a regular expression replacement for this:

```
$inputFile = 'C:\path\to\your.log'
$outputFile = 

$re = '([A-Z]{2}\d+) - (\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) - ' +
      '(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) -$'

(Get-Content 'C:\input.txt') -match $re -replace ".*$re", '$1;$2:$3;$4' |
    Set-Content 'C:\output.txt'
```

If you want the rest of the content left in place and just change the format of the `DD890 - 07/15/2016 10:23:46 - 139.18.40.21 -` substrings remove the `-match` operation and the additional `.*` in the replacement search string:

```
(Get-Content 'C:\input.txt') -replace $re, '$1;$2:$3;$4' |
    Set-Content 'C:\output.txt'
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you only need the lines containing "Model number: ", use `Where-Object` to filter on those and then split each string and join them back together:

```
Get-Content .\file.txt|Where-Object {$_ -like '*Model number*'} |ForEach-Object {
    # Remote the timestamp and "Model number: " string
    # then split by "-" and finally Trim() whitespace off each resulting substring
    $parts = $_ -replace '^[\d\s:]+Model number: ','').Split('-',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)|%{$_.Trim()}

    # concatenate the parts back together with -join
    $parts -join ';'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I spread out many of the variable assignments, to hopefully give you some visibility on each individual step, as opposed to shorter code, that would require excessive explanation to someone unfamiliar with the process:

```
$outputFile = "c:\test\output.txt"
$inputFile = "c:\test\input.txt"
if (Test-Path $outputFile)
    {Remove-Item $outputFile}
$fileData = Get-Content $inputFile
foreach ($line in $fileData)
{
    if ($line -like "*Model number*")
    {
        $newline = $line -replace ".*Model number: ", ""
        $newline = $newline -replace " - ", ";"
        $newline = $newline.TrimEnd(" -")
        $newline = $newline -replace " ", ";"
        Add-Content $outputFile $newline
    }
}
```

Your sample data, as provided in the question, would look like this in `output.txt` afterwards:

```
DD890;07/15/2016;10:23:46;139.18.40.21
DD890;07/15/2016;10:23:46;103.153.18.28
DD890;07/15/2016;10:23:46;12.19.41.75
DD880;07/15/2016;10:23:46;103.6.28.71
DD890;07/15/2016;10:23:46;10.116.83.12
DD4500;07/15/2016;10:23:46;10.18.31.86
DD4500;07/15/2016;10:23:46;10.18.23.10
```

(**NOTE**: I'm assuming that you had a typo between the MM/DD/YYYY and HH:MM:SS data, as you had a `:` but I think you meant `;`  If not, adjust the very last `-replace` to a `:` instead.)